# PHP What functions can be called on mysqli get_result objects?

Tags: php, mysqli

What kind of functions can be run on the object that gets returned by `mysqli_stmt_get_result()`.

```
//after running a query
$result = $stmt->get_result();

//I know this one
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result){}

//However this didnt work on this query for me.
SELECT MAX id FROM users;
```

So what are other ways to get data from $result and in what cases are they used?

Comment: I'd say the methods implemented in the object are a good start. http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: From the PHP manual for `mysqli_stmt_get_result()`: _Available only with mysqlnd_ . `mysqlnd` is frequently not installed, so your code won't work for reasons not related to your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you it isn't because that query should be:

```
select max(id) from users
```

There are many methods of retrieving data from the result object: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: that link was all I needed thanks :p. And hate to different type of SQL syntaxes